# facebook post friends wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

is there any way to send data to users' wall or newsfeed from application(not from another user) who granted the application

Comment: So you want to have a function to spam someones Wall even you're not friends?

Comment: Also note that you can't have two FB accounts, as that is a violation of the ToS.

Comment: for example  I am a shop owner and like to send data from admin page.I select facebook user id by checkbox and press submit button and then data is sent to the customer`s wall page. or application will send data to customers wall or may be from cron system.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I can conceive of both ethical and unethical uses for this functionality.  I can even conceive of ways to solve msaif's use case without enabling spam, though without knowing his reasons for wanting this code I don't know if they will solve his problem.  Regardless, I prefer to give him the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

No. That would allow spam to run rampant throughout Facebook.

Perhaps you want advertising instead: https://www.facebook.com/advertising/

Comment: is there any way to post data to users wall from application who accepts that application and also grants publish_stream.

Comment: Don't you understand what "No." means?

Comment: @msaif: If the user allows your app with the necessary permissions, that should be possible. It's a completely different question though, and IIRC it was answered somewhere on SO (try searching for it).

Comment: can you give me that link, I did not find,I have a trouble on this,pls help