# facebook mail read

Tags: facebook, email

In facebook,A and B are not friends but they all accepted read_mailbox for an application.
now A need to read messages of B`s mailbox. How can be done this using PHP?

may be not possible,if not possible, then if A and B are friends then will it be possible graph api?

I solved but the following rules ,pls let me know if any problem.

a and b all are accepted read_mailbox account now a can read mail of b and b can read mail of a using application token not user`s token

Answer (score 2):

For both parts of your question the answer is a big **NO**.

This is [not the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743920/facebook-post-friends-wall) you ask a malicious question. I'm not sure what your goals are but this way, I can assure you that your Facebook App will get removed and even worse..your Facebook account may get deactivated.

Comment: Yup, Facebook basically wants their API to augment the site's services, and not go against the TOS. Even if both users agree to `read_mailbox` it's against the TOS for users to share accounts.

Comment: a and b all are accepted read_mailbox account now a can read mail of b and b can read mail of a using application token not user`s token